# How to write "only for female" on jeans tag

Tags: word-choice

We want to indicate that jeans are for only female on the tag.

1. Only female
2. Only woman
3. For woman
4. For women
5. For female

Which one is viable? Are there any better one?

Comment: I don't understand "on the tag" any more than the original "at the etiquette". Do you mean "text written on an identifying tag attached to a pair of jeans offered for sale"?

Comment: yes I mean on the tag .

Comment: Is this for a real 'bricks and mortar' physical shopping outlet? Where the expected customers are predominantly native English speakers? If that's the case, simply go to other nearby shops selling similar products, and copy their wording. If it's an online shop, copy what you find most often on Ebay.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Please support it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"For Her" or "For Women" are common terms used to describe a sub-brand of clothing or other sundry that is targeted to women exclusively, especially if the brand is historically gender-neutral or traditionally targeted men. For instance, the Gilette brand of razor blades was uniquely identified with men shaving their faces, until it became popular in the 40s and 50s for women to shave their underarms and legs, and women expressed dissatisfaction with the available male-oriented designs, at which point Gilette responded with various "Gilette for Women" products that met a different but overlapping set of needs.

So, "Jeans for Her" or "Jeans for Women" are perfectly fine to describe your item here.

If the article has a "French" theme, "Pour Femme", literally "For Woman", would work and would be understood by English speakers, however in English, unless a thing is intended for one single person, and nobody else would ever want it, the use of the singular gender is seldom or ever used.

Avoid using the word "female" in this case and most others; it sounds too clinical, and many women in the U.S. would look at something labelled "Jeans For Females" and think they were being objectified, or if they saw "female jeans" they'd think the jeans themselves were being given the gender. The only exceptions are when "female" is used as part of common colloquisms, such as "the female form" which refers to the general shape of a woman in the abstract.

Answer (score 3):

The normal way you would refer to jeans for ladies is

> Women's Jeans

Comment: What about for shirts or any other clothes ?

Comment: Women's Shirts and Women's clothing or Woman's wear

Comment: Or Young Women's for girls.

Answer (score 2):

I think none of OP's suggestions are really appropriate. In a context where OP feels the word 'etiquette' is relevant, neither 'women' nor 'female' are really the right kind of words to distinguish gender.

Assuming I understand *at the etiquette* correctly, as meaning "in some written text specifying acceptable dress standards" [for some event/location], the most acceptable form is probably ...

[black tie, etc.], **jeans (ladies only)**, [no open-neck shirts, etc.]

If the only requirement is text for an identifying label on a pair of jeans offered for sale, it should be **Ladies jeans**. This is the standard term distinguishing them from **Men's jeans** (which may or may not have an apostrophe, though the *Ladies* version almost *never* does).

Comment: Not an interpretation I'd considered but you could be right.  I assumed the tag mentioned was a clothing product tag.

Comment: actually I meant "on the tag".